# Collapse legend in QField 1.6.0+

Tags: qgis, qfield

Is it any way to make layer list collapsible in newest QField? Or can I change project settings the way legend contains only list of layers without symbology variants? Because now I have almost infinite scroll in my QField project with all layers and its variants.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already reported in the QField Issues https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1234. You can interact with Opengis.ch staff for improve this feature

Comment: I ran into the same problem using the current version. Has there been a new feature to solve the problem, since the question was asked?